# Numpy doesn't throw FloatingPointError for dot product

Tags: python, numpy, integer-overflow

I am taking the dot-product of two numpy arrays (both `float32`). I am deliberately setting numpy to raise a `FloatingPointError` in case of overflow. However, `dot` does not behave as expected: instead of raising a `FloatingPointError` as it does when using ordinary multiplication, `dot` returns `inf`.

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to force `dot` to raise an exception as well?

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

np.seterr(over="raise")

x = np.array([2e+38], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([10], dtype=np.float32)

x * y
>>> FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in multiply

np.dot(x,y)
>>> inf
```

Comment: A guess - `dot` is using a BLAS library that doesn't  detect this.

Comment: `matmul` does give the warning, `x@y`.  You don't need to use `dot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting @hpaulj's comment as the answer – `matmul` does throw a `FloatingPointError` as required, while `dot` doesn't (no idea why). For my purpose `matmul` gives the same result as `dot`.